# support for regex look behind and ahead?

Tags: regular-expressions

I need to perform regex query replace, such that

`foo` in `foo bar` is matched, but `foo` in `foo baz` is not. Normally I would use regex look ahead, e.g. `foo(?=bar)`.

However, it seems like Emacs cannot do this? [Vim seems capable](https://jbodah.github.io/blog/2016/11/01/positivenegative-lookaheadlookbehind-vim/), but evil mode in spacemacs cannot.

Comment: There's also this: https://github.com/gamesun/emacs-regex-lookaround, but I didn't try building with this patch, and it looks like it's been a while.

Comment: Shelling out to `perl` can work in some use cases.

Answer (score 19):

No, Emacs regular expressions do not support arbitrary zero-width look-ahead/behind assertions.

n.b. Evil and Spacemacs (like all elisp libraries) are irrelevant when it comes to questions about the Emacs Lisp language implementation.

Comment: So is it impossible to replace `foo` in `foobar` but not in `foobaz`? This is a common enough operation that I thought there must be a solution. Perhaps looking ahead and behind is the wrong approach?

Comment: This isn't strictly equivalent, but replacing `foo\(bar\)` with `baz\1` will be sufficient in all cases where `bar` didn't contain further matches.

Comment: If you're writing elisp, you have lots of flexibility, and if you're replacing interactively you can invoke arbitrary elisp during replacements, so ultimately there are ways to do these things. Just not as conveniently as you might do with those assertions.

Comment: e.g.: replacing `foo` with `\,(if (looking-at "bar") "baz" \&)` will replace `foo` with `baz` if the following text is `bar` (and replace `foo` with `foo` otherwise). Which still isn't the same thing as only *matching* `foo` when it's followed by `bar`, but it's another option.

Comment: I guess this is like what you said above, but it seems like you can type: C-S-M-% foo \\(bar\\) RET FOO \1 RET to replace all foo bar with FOO bar, but leave all foo baz alone. Is this missing some thing you wanted?

Answer (score 6):

https://github.com/benma/visual-regexp-steroids.el/

Visual regexp steroids allows you to replace, search, etc. using python regex. Python regex  has support for look ahead and look behind.

It even highlights the regexp expressions for you.

[image: regexp example]

Comment: Well, highlighting is also available without that, at least I have it in Doom, but good tip :)